# Split CSV file into multiple files by column-data

Tags: python, parsing, csv, split

I want to split a "source.csv" file based on it's contents. But of course it's not just simple splitting, but I need to fullfill some "rules".

1. The source and destination files have a fixed header which aren't properly csv formated.
2. The new files are named based on a special data in one of the columns (in my example here the "Fruit" column)
3. It needs to be OS independent.
4. The source-csv file can contain about 500.000+ rows with at least 30+ columns. (Scientific data) So I'm not sure if it's good to keep the whole data in ram, or just read from file line by line and directly sorting in about 500+ files, based on the value of the "Fruit"-Column.

Something like this would be great:

## source file: source.csv

```
Author: Somebody
Date: Christmas
Project-Title: 42
Name, Fruit, Blubb, Drobblwubb
Anton, Apple, 234, NewYork
Bettina, Banana, 234, Chicago
Carolin, Apple, 123, Berlin
```

## Destination file1: out/destination_apple.csv

```
Author: Somebody
Date: Christmas
Project-Title: 42
Name, Fruit, Blubb, Drobblwubb
Anton, Apple, 234, NewYork
Carolin, Apple, 123, Berlin
```

## Destination file2: out/destination_banana.csv

```
Author: Somebody
Date: Christmas
Project-Title: 42
Name, Fruit, Blubb, Drobblwubb
Bettina, Banana, 234, Chicago
```

I'm experimenting quite a lot, but haven't got any really "pythonic" or even working code yet :/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the python `pandas` module? It is a great module for data processing and will help you very much. Something like this can help you on the way:

```
import pandas

csv = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', header=3, skipinitialspace=True)
# header=3 because your header is on the third line
# skipinitialspace is set to True because your example data has spaces after commas
csv_apples = csv[csv['Fruit'] == 'Apple']
csv_bananas = csv[csv['Fruit'] == 'Banana']

csv_apples.to_csv('apples.csv', index=False, sep=',')
csv_bananas.to_csv('bananas.csv', index=False, sep=',')
```

This example does not write the first 3 lines of your original csv to the resulting csv. You can implement this reading the first three lines the csv separately and passing it in the `to_csv` function with `header=yourheader`

Comment: This sounds great! Thank you. Will test it and report back after success/failure :).