# How to split one csv into multiple files in python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I have a csv file (world.csv) looks like this :

```
"city","city_alt","lat","lng","country"
"Mjekić","42.6781","20.9728","Kosovo"
"Mjekiff","42.6781","20.9728","Kosovo"
"paris","42.6781","10.9728","France"
"Bordeau","16.6781","52.9728","France"
"Menes","02.6781","50.9728","Morocco"
"Fess","6.6781","3.9728","Morocco"
"Tanger","8.6781","5.9728","Morocco"
```

And i want to split it to multiple file by country like this:

Kosovo.csv :

```
"city","city_alt","lat","lng","country"
"Mjekić","42.6781","20.9728","Kosovo"
"Mjekiff","42.6781","20.9728","Kosovo"
```

France.csv :

```
"city","city_alt","lat","lng","country"
"paris","42.6781","10.9728","France"
"Bordeau","16.6781","52.9728","France"
```

Morroco.csv :

```
"city","city_alt","lat","lng","country"
"Menes","02.6781","50.9728","Morocco"
"Fess","6.6781","3.9728","Morocco"
"Tanger","8.6781","5.9728","Morocco"
```

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680382/split-csv-file-into-multiple-files-by-column-data

Comment: load to `pandas.DataFrame` and then you can easily select rows and save only selected rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't use pandas you can use the built-in `csv` module and `itertools.groupby()` function. You can use this to group by country.

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv

with open('world.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader) #skip header
    
    #Group by column (country)
    lst = sorted(reader, key=lambda x : x[4])
    groups = groupby(lst, key=lambda x : x[4])

    #Write file for each country
    for k,g in groups:
        filename = k + '.csv'
        with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as fout:
            csv_output = csv.writer(fout)
            csv_output.writerow(["city","city_alt","lat","lng","country"])  #header
            for line in g:
                csv_output.writerow(line)
```

Comment: it give me a lot off csv file with same country

Comment: i need one csv for one country

Comment: @FlutterLover Using your world.csv I get three files: Morocco.csv, Kosovo.csv and France.csv. Isn't that what you want? What files do you get?

Comment: @FlutterLover I just noticed in your world.csv file the one column seems to be missing. There are five column names in the header but only four in the actual data. Perhaps it was a copy and paste error? Try changing x[3] to x[4] in my code if the data contains five columns.

Comment: Yes now working by changing x[3] to x[4]
Thanks a lot

Comment: @FlutterLover Great!

Answer (score 4):

try this:

filter the columns based on the country name. Then convert that to csv file using `to_csv` in `pandas`

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

france = df[df['country']=='France']
kosovo = df[df['country']=='Kosovo']
morocco = df[df['country']=='Morocco']

france.to_csv('france.csv', index=False)
kosovo.to_csv('kosovo.csv', index=False)
morocco.to_csv('morocco.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest way to do this is as below:**
#create a folder called "adata" for example in your working directory
#import glob

```
for i,g in df.groupby('CITY'):
    g.to_csv('adata\{}.csv'.format(i), header=True, index_label='Index')
print(glob.glob('adata\*.csv'))
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('adata\*.csv'))

for f in filenames:
    #your intended processes
```