# How to Separate Dataframe Based on the Label value?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

Let say I have this dataframe.

```
+-----------------+-----------+
|     COMMENT     | SENTIMENT |
+-----------------+-----------+
| Good app        | Positive  |
| Bad app         | Negative  |
| Useless feature | Negative  |
| I like this app | Positive  |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

I want to split it based on the SENTIMENT column. Like this below.

```
+-----------------+-----------+
|     COMMENT     | SENTIMENT |
+-----------------+-----------+
| Good app        | Positive  |
| I like this app | Positive  |
+-----------------+-----------+


+-----------------+-----------+
|     COMMENT     | SENTIMENT |
+-----------------+-----------+
| Bad app         | Negative  |
| Useless feature | Negative  |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

Anyone knows the solution in Python (Jupyter) for that case? Your help will help my thesis project. Thank you :D

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split one csv into multiple files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60425658/how-to-split-one-csv-into-multiple-files-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use `df1 = df[df["SENTIMENT"]=="Positive"]`

Then `df1` will have:

[image]

`df2 = df[df["SENTIMENT"]=="Negative"]`

Then `df2` will have:

[image]